# Proof attempt for limit of a function defined by another function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

Let $lim_{x \to 0}f(x) = L $. Let $a\gt0$, and define $ g(x):=f(ax) $. Prove that $lim_{x \to 0}g(x) = L$

Proof attempt:
Let $\epsilon \gt0. $ Then $|x|\lt \delta \Rightarrow |ax| \lt a\delta \Rightarrow |f(ax)-L| \lt \epsilon \Rightarrow |g(x) -L|\lt \epsilon \Rightarrow lim_{x \to 0}g(x) = L $

Is the above proof correct? Any feedback is appreciated!

Comment: You cannot deduce $|f(ax)-L|<\epsilon$ with $|ax|<a\delta$. What you need instead is $|ax|<\delta$, this would make the deduction correct. Also, try to write more quantifiers, it would make the proof clearer.

Comment: $\forall \epsilon \gt 0, \exists \delta$ such that $|x| < \delta \Rightarrow |x| < \frac\delta a \lt \delta \Rightarrow |ax| \lt \delta.$ Is this better?

Comment: No, it is not, your implications are false. Pose $\delta'=\frac{\delta}{a}$

Comment: I see, so we need to find a new $\delta$ that satisfy the condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I would redact it like below.

$\lim\limits_{x\to 0} f(x)=L\quad$ is equivalent to $\quad\forall\varepsilon >0,\ \exists\,\delta_1 >0, \ \text{such that } |x|<\delta_1\Rightarrow |f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$

So given $a>0$ and for $\delta_2=\frac{\delta_1}a >0$ we have

$|x|<\delta_2\Rightarrow |ax|<\delta_1\Rightarrow |f(ax)-L|<\varepsilon\Rightarrow |g(x)-L|<\varepsilon$

So $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} g(x)=L$ .

Answer (score 0):

Given $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists\, \delta(\epsilon)>0 : |f(\delta(\epsilon)) - L| < \epsilon \Rightarrow \left|f\left(a \cdot\frac{\delta(\epsilon)}{a}\right) - L\right| < \epsilon \Rightarrow \left|g\left(\frac{\delta(\epsilon)}{a}\right) - L\right| < \epsilon \Rightarrow \left|g(\delta'(\epsilon)) - L\right| < \epsilon$ where $\delta'(\epsilon) = \dfrac{\delta(\epsilon)}{a} >0 \Rightarrow \lim_{x\to 0} g(x) = L$.